# Regarding Daemon thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I was doing a sort of research in which I want to make a user thread as a daemon thread ,Thread.setDaemon(true) makes a Thread daemon, but as we knowDaemon Threads are suitable for doing background job, so I want to link my this thread to any background daemon thread so that my daemon thread can provide some services to that thread and it should end when that daemon threads end, although I have created the daemon thread but please advise how I would provide the services through my daemon thread to any existing daemon thread and then it should end up at last, please advise.

```
     Thread daemonThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
           public void run(){
               try{
               while(true){
                   System.out.println("Daemon thread is running");
               }

               }catch(Exception e){

               }finally{
                   System.out.println("Daemon Thread exiting"); //never called
               }
           }
       }, "Daemon-Thread");

       daemonThread.setDaemon(true); //making this thread daemon
       daemonThread.start();


}
```

Comment: What services do you want to provide by your daemon thread?

Comment: "I want to link my this thread to any background daemon thread so that my daemon thread can provide some services to that thread". Define "link".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean but I would change

```
while(true){
```

to

```
while(!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()){
```

This will allow your thread to stop when interrupted.

I would also consider using an ExecutorService as this makes it easier to pass work to another thread and shut it down when you are finished.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r, "worker");
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    }
});

service.submit(new Runnable() { /* task for this thread to perform */ });

service.shutdown(); // to stop it.
```

Comment: Can you please advise if using executor service can I make a thread as daemon , and if yes then my daemon thread will provide the service to any existing daemon thread..!!

Comment: ,Thanks a lot, but could you also please explain rite now thread is being converted to daemon but now as Per the query if My this daemon thread should provide some sort of service to any exisiting daemon thread.

Comment: I have added an example where you can pass tasks as Runnable to the background thread and stop it when you don't need it any more.

Comment: Why did you write "while IS interrupted"? Shouldn't that be in the negative? Also, what if there is an `InterruptedException` in the block, caught by the no-op catch-block, and the interrupt-flag reset?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Indeed it should. If you discard the interrupt, it will be discarded.  If you ignore exceptions which are actually important you are always going to have problems.

Comment: I asked this to the benefit of OP. He obviously needs not one but three-four lessons :)

Comment: 'This will allow your thread to stop when interrupted' - why bother if the thread is never going to stop?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Thanks a lot could you please show the full program that will make understanding more clear.Thanks

Comment: @MartinJames I wouldn't except I thought the OP wanted the option of stopping this thread when the one which uses it stops.

Comment: @Peter please can you show the complete program in terms of code as I have done above that will make understanding more clear.Thanks, I want to start a normal thread and then convert it into daemon and then link it to any daemon thread ,Thanks

Comment: The example I have given has all the elements of the example you gave except it doesn't have a thread start/stopped message. Do you have a more concrete requirement which can be turned into an example?